# Data transformation from array to multipicklist in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api

I have a one on one mapping with every field in a custom object to a field in an external system. I have a multipicklist that is mapped to an array of external system, now when the data is passed it errors out with restricted picklist error, how to transform data from array to multi pick list in salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multipickist values are stored in a string that separates each value by a semicolon.  So if you have `Apple` `Orange` and `Banana` all selected as values for a Contact.My_Multi_Picklist__c, they can be saved in the Salesforce field as follows:

```
Contact.My_Multi_Picklist__c = 'Apple;Orange;Banana';
```

If you're getting an array of strings and want to convert to a multipicklist value, `String.join()` should do the trick, using `;` as the separator:

```
List<String> incomingStrArray = new List<String>{'Apple','Orange','Banana'};
Contact.My_Multi_Picklist__c = String.join(incomingStrArray,';');
```